# How to download in-memory file from Blazor server-side

Tags: file, download, blazor, blazor-server-side

Is there a way to download a file, generated dynamically *in memory* in **Blazor** *Server Side* without need to store it on a filesystem?

Comment: I don't think there is anthing built into Blazor but you can add an MVC Controller and generate the file there. So construct an URL with the parameters to do that. But consider if that could be exploited.

Comment: Henk, yes, the good approach will be to add MVC controller into Blazor server side app. Unfortunately, the most suggestions, googled in the web are about adding Blazor into existing MVC - not vice versa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution was in adding *Web Api* contoller into Blazor server side app.

1. Add `Controllers/DownloadController.cs` controller to the root of Blazor app:

```cs
[ApiController, Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class DownloadController : ControllerBase {

        [HttpGet, Route("{name}")]
        public ActionResult Get(string name) {

            var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello! Content is here.");
            var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
            //var stream = new FileStream(filename);

            var result = new FileStreamResult(stream, "text/plain");
            result.FileDownloadName = "test.txt";
            return result;
        }


    }
```

2. Adjust `Startup.cs` of the Blazor app to support controllers routing:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {

            ...

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action}");

                endpoints.MapControllers();

                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

            });

        }
```

Comment: Thanks, works well and can't get simpler.
However, an annoying thig is that the download web api url will show up on the adress bar, obviously, while this can be avoided when using a javascript based download routine or just when downloading a file with plain a/href with download attribute (as seen on https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp). Not sure how to get around this without JS interop.

Comment: The above issue very easily avoided using JS-interop as described here; https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/10358/how-to-create-a-pdf-file-in-blazor-using-c

Comment: Blazor server side is not suposed to have a Controller

Comment: @MarchalPT - Why is it not supposed to?  Do you have a link for that?  [citation needed]

Comment: @HenkHolterman For start, you can download without an api, using a cshtml page
and of course you can add an API for specific endpoints but the whole point of Blazor server is to run all code in server.

Answer (score 4):

Create a cshtml page in Blazor like bellow.

FileDownload.cshtml.cs:

```
public class FileDownloadsModel : PageModel
{        
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
    {
        byte[] fileContent = ....;                                  

        return File(fileContent, "application/force-download", "test.txt");
    }       
}
```

FileDownload.cshtml:

```
@page "/download/{object}/{id:int}/{fileType}" 
@model GFProdMan.Pages.FileDownloadsModel
```

And that is simply it.

Comment: You do know that cshtml (Razor Pages) is a lightweight Controller model?

Comment: doesnt need to attach an API

Comment: but this is opening a new page right? you should navigate to the download url?

Comment: This will open and close a new page triggering the download, you wont notice that